# Pythonic way for double iteration (list all files with extensions)

Tags: python

Given a base path and a list with extensions the task is to list all files:

Two of my solutions are:

```
from glob import glob
from os import path

EXTENSIONS = ['*.zip', '*.jar', '*.pdf']
DOC_PATH = '/path/to/files'

# Solution1:
files = []         
for ext in EXTENSIONS:
    files.extend(glob(path.join(DOC_PATH, ext)))
# works but looks very clumsy

# Solution2:
files = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,
               [glob(path.join(DOC_PATH, ext)) for ext in EXTENSIONS])
# Also functional but looks like a misuse of reduce
```

Have you got any other ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure how idiomatic/efficient it is : `sum((glob(path.join(DOC_PATH, ext)) for ext in EXTENSIONS), [])` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to iterate over them (once) and not an actual list, you could use `itertools.chain` and `glob.iglob`:

```
files = chain(*(iglob(path.join(DOC_PATH, ext)) for ext in EXTENSIONS))
```

If you do need an actual list, you can further call `list(files)`, of course.

Comment: `chain` is quite a good idea

Answer (score 3):

Using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os
EXTENSIONS = 'zip jar pdf'.split()
EXTENSION_SET = set('.' + e for e in EXTENSIONS)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(DOC_PATH) if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in EXTENSION_SET]
```

Using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import os
import re
EXTENSIONS = 'zip jar pdf'.split()
EXTENSION_RE = re.compile(r'\.({})$'.format('|'.join(EXTENSIONS))
files = [f for f in os.listdir(DOC_PATH) if EXTENSION_RE.search(f)]
# or files = list(filter(EXTENSION_RE.search, os.listdir(DOC_PATH)))
```

The advantage of these approaches is that you only iterate over the files in the directory once (rather than once for each extension, as in the `glob` case).